# Creating dynamic multiple UIButton programmatically

Tags: swift, uibutton, swift4

I am creating my UI programmatically, and this is how I create a button

```
let button: UIButton = {

let button = UIButton()
button.setTitle("Try1",.normal)
return button

}
```

[image]

And this is what I want to do. For example movie1 has got 2 categories, Dram & Horror I just want to show 2 of them. 
Movie2 has got 4 categories, Dram&Horror&Sport& War i just want to show 4 of them.

And now Im stuck I have NO idea what to do. I know you guys gonna give minus rep but I need help.

**Done! Solution is below**

First I have made a struct

```
struct Category {
let title: String
let color: UIColor
init(title: String, color: UIColor) {
    self.title = title
    self.color = color
}
}
```

Then I made an empty array type of Category Struct

```
var categories = [Category]()
/* I appended some stuff manually to this array */
    categories.append(Category(title: "Dram", color: Colors.cherry))
    categories.append(Category(title: "Sport", color: Colors.lightGreen))
    categories.append(Category(title: "Horror", color: Colors.purple))
    categories.append(Category(title: "War", color: Colors.darkBlue))

/* Then I made a for loop */
 for category in categories{
        let button = UIButton()
        button.createButton(title: category.title, titleColor: .white, fontType: "bold", fontSize: 17, background: category.color, cornerRadius: 4)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
```

[image]

Comment: you should use collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Horizontal StackView for that. In StackView you can add as much arranged subviews as you want and it will be automatically adjusting to the available space. Just setup constraints for StackView and rest will just work out of the box.

You can add your button to StackView using:

```
stackView.addArangedSubview(button)
```

To create button you can simple use for loop:

```
for i in 1...3 { //change 3 to your value
    let button = UIButton()
    stackView.addArangedSubview(button)
}
```

Comment: Well im actually looking for creating buttons. What I want is creating buttons for the data. If the response data is like = ["Horror","Sport"] I'd like to create 2 button automatically.

Comment: You can create the buttons according to data using a stackview also.

Comment: I've edited my answer with a for loop that will create a buttons for you. It's really easy

Comment: Uhm, its hard to figure it out. Im going to explain it: 

I want to have one button, for example with 100x200px and background color is black and title is Button. Then according to the data I want to multiple it for example change background color to blue and title Data1, background color red and title Data2

Comment: So create an array of your titles and colors and while creating buttons get those data from arrays.

This is not the best solution but I think the easiest one for you

Comment: But how Im gonna put them in a loop?

Comment: On every loop you have your index in 'i' variable. If you have for example array named buttonColors you can get a color from there by doing: let color = buttonColors[i]

Comment: Also remember that arrays are starting with index 0 :)

Comment: Yeah i know that :) Uhm is there any place that I can reach you by private message? I need a huge help :/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multiple buttons in horizontal then add button in scrollview

**Swift 4.0**

```
func ButtonCreation() {

   yourScrollviewname.isScrollEnabled = true
    yourScrollviewname.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let numberOfButtons = 16 
    let numberofRows = 1 
    var count = 0
    var px = 0
    var py = 0

    for _ in 1...numberofRows {
        px = 0

        if count < numberOfButtons {
            for j in 1...numberOfButtons{
                count += 1

                let Button = UIButton()
                Button.tag = count
                Button.frame = CGRect(x: px, y: 0, width: 80, height: 27)
                Button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
                Button.layer.masksToBounds = true
                Button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: .normal)
                print(colorArr[j-1])
                Button.setTitle(colorText[j-1], for: .normal)
                Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scrollButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
               yourScrollviewname.addSubview(Button)
                px = px + Int(yourScrollviewname.frame.width)/2 - 50
            }
        }else{

            for j in numberOfButtons/2...numberOfButtons {
                count += 1

                let Button = UIButton()
                Button.tag = count
                Button.frame = CGRect(x: px+10, y: py+10, width: 80, height: 427)
                Button.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
                Button.setTitle("Hello \(j) ", for: .normal)
                Button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(scrollButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
                yourScrollviewname.addSubview(Button)
                px = px + Int(yourScrollviewname.frame.width)/2 - 30
            }


        }

        py =  Int(yourScrollviewname.frame.height)-70
    }

    yourScrollviewname.contentSize = CGSize(width: px, height: py)

}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Swift 3.0 ...**

```
let stackview = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 512, height: 356)) // set your postion 
   stackview.axis = . Horizontal
    stackview.spacing = 10.0
    stackview.alignment = .Fill
    stackview.distribution = .EqualSpacing

    for i in 1...3 {
     let button = UIButton()
     stackview.addArangedSubview(button)
    }
```